# How to use resultset if query has count(column_name)

Tags: jakarta-ee

my query is
select count(nominee_id) from vote group by nominee_id

how to get the count value using result set in java.
Also I need to know whether my query is right.

I have a table, from which i need to count the number of votes polled.

My table(vote) has columns like
vote_id
nominee_id
voter_id

Comment: Can you give us some more context, some of the code you already have. At the moment it is fairly difficult to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select count(nom_id) from vote group by nom_id");

Comment: Using rs I need to display the count of nom_id

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a `java.sql.ResultSet`, just say `resultSet.getInt(1)`, which returns the first column of the result, in this case the count value.

Comment: I am getting exception for this.

Comment: Stating the exception might be helpful @KirithikaM

Answer (score 0):

If what you're doing is trying to find out how many votes each nominee received, then yes your query looks ok, from what I can tell from your description.

Regarding the java, something like this:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("select count(nominee_id) from vote group by nominee_id");
```

Comment: I need to display the count value in the text box. I need to know how to get the count value using result(ResultSet)

Comment: To count all entires in the ResultSet you could: `while (rs.next()) {
  count++;
}` and then use count populate the text box with the value of count.

Comment: What was your chosen answer?

Comment: Using count variable I displayed the result. while(rs.next()){ coun++; } I chose this. Its working.

Comment: Can you select your chosen answer so that people know what your solution was, and to give rep?